# how to pass a javascript object (a url) from one view to another view using mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

View1.cshtml:

```
          <script>
          var selectedImage;
         function select(image) {
            var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
            var index = 0, length = images.length;
            for (; index < length; index++) {
                images[index].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            selectedImage = image.id;
            image.classList.add('selected');
            var image = document.getElementById(selectedImage);
            var audioId = image.getAttribute('data-audio')
            var audioElement = document.getElementById(audioId);


                // Check browser supporta
                if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    // Store
                    localStorage.setItem("audiourl", audioElement);

                    // Retrieve
                     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("audiourl");
                }
```

```
       <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <audio id="audio1" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Record)"></audio>
     <audio id="audio2" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Word_Record)"></audio>

    <img id="img1" data-audio="audio1" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Pic)" alt="" onclick="select(this)"  />

    <img id="img2" data-audio="audio2" src="@Url.Content(item.Letter_Word)" alt="" onclick="select(this)" />
           </div>
```

This is view1 here is an audiourl  in the javascript that  i have to pass in view2.cshtml in a c# function. i have to pass an object of javascript  from view 1  to view 2 and store this as an argument . the code i have used above is storing the  value in local storage but how to retrieve this value in a variable of another view so that i can call it my function of view 2 ?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve a variable from "localStorage" in C# code? If so, "localStorage" is a client-side object and cannot be accessed on the server.
If however you're planning to do it in javascript, you can use 
localStorage.getItem("audiourl");
or
localStorage["audiourl"]

Comment: Are 'View1' and 'View2' the views of two different controller actions or are they both used to display the results of one single action. In case of two different actions, you should supply the data as an argument in the url when you call the second controller action.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart  yes they are of two different action . can u please elaborate your answer? the 2nd view  will be executed on click .

Comment: @JodiSupporter i am already using localStorage.getItem("audiourl");  but the problem is that i have to call this value in c# code that is define in another view.

Comment: In the 'onClick', you will have to fetch the data from the local storage and include it as a parameter in the URL to the second action (should result in something like 'http://localhost/Audio/Action2?audiourl=my%encoded%url'. Don't forget to include the encoded value as the parameter, otherwise it will result in exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding it right, but you want to pass information between two controller methods that gets the views right?

Comment: @ObedMarsh  I actually want to pass the information between two views. Basically an audioUrl (html object we get from javascript while an image is being selected) from one view to another view in which we right our required logic (c# Function which takes a url as an argument). Controller actions do nothing but calling views.

Comment: You can easily make a nullable parameter fx in a views get method and pass something into it like that and include the information - in a link fx - using razor in the first view.